# Getting error while downloading node modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am working on angular 7 and I was trying to download npm module called 'ngx-image-cropper'. But it was throwing some errors like :.

```
npm ERR! Invalid package name "no,rmalize-path": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/administartor/.npm/_logs/2020-03-28T05_08_25_516Z-debug.log

Command used: npm i ngx-image-cropper
```

Then I tried deleting all node_modules and now I am getting same error for npm install. Now I can't even install my old modules.

I am using node version : v12.5.0

and npm version : 6.9.0.

my package.json file:

```
  "name": "Project-abcd",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~7.2.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.13.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^2.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Error log file is as follows:

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'i'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.5.0
4 verbose npm-session af89b225baade24d
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall ats-candidate-frontend@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle ats-candidate-frontend@0.0.0~preinstall: ats-candidate-frontend@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 1564ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 13ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
16 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1907ms
17 silly saveTree ats-candidate-frontend@0.0.0
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ @angular-devkit/core@7.2.4
17 silly saveTree │ │ └── ajv@6.6.2
17 silly saveTree │ ├── @angular-devkit/schematics@7.2.4
17 silly saveTree │ └─┬ @schematics/angular@7.2.4
17 silly saveTree │   └── typescript@3.2.2
17 silly saveTree ├── @angular/router@7.2.16
17 silly saveTree ├── @angular/service-worker@7.2.16
17 silly saveTree ├── @kolkov/angular-editor@0.13.1
17 silly saveTree ├── @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4.1.0
17 silly saveTree ├── @types/jasmine@2.8.16
17 silly saveTree ├── @types/jasminewd2@2.0.8
17 silly saveTree ├── @types/node@8.9.5
17 silly saveTree ├── bootstrap@4.4.1
17 silly saveTree ├── classlist.js@1.1.20150312
17 silly saveTree ├─┬ codelyzer@4.5.0
17 silly saveTree │ ├── app-root-path@2.2.1
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ css-selector-tokenizer@0.7.2
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── cssesc@3.0.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ └── fastparse@1.1.2
17 silly saveTree │ ├── cssauron@1.4.0
17 silly saveTree │ ├── source-map@0.5.7
17 silly saveTree │ └── sprintf-js@1.1.2
17 silly saveTree ├── core-js@2.6.11
17 silly saveTree ├── crypto-js@3.3.0
17 silly saveTree ├── hammerjs@2.0.8
17 silly saveTree ├── jasmine-core@2.99.1
17 silly saveTree ├─┬ jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
17 silly saveTree │ └── colors@1.1.2
17 silly saveTree ├── jquery@3.4.1
17 silly saveTree ├─┬ karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
17 silly saveTree │ └── fs-access@1.0.1
17 silly saveTree ├─┬ karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.6
17 silly saveTree │ └─┬ istanbul-api@2.1.6
17 silly saveTree │   ├── async@2.6.3
17 silly saveTree │   ├── compare-versions@3.6.0
17 silly saveTree │   ├── fileset@2.0.3
17 silly saveTree │   ├── istanbul-lib-coverage@2.0.5
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ istanbul-lib-hook@2.0.7
17 silly saveTree │   │ └─┬ append-transform@1.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   │   └─┬ default-require-extensions@2.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   │     └── strip-bom@3.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ istanbul-lib-instrument@3.3.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├─┬ @babel/generator@7.8.7
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ ├─┬ @babel/types@7.8.7
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@2.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ ├── jsesc@2.5.2
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ └── source-map@0.5.7
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├── @babel/parser@7.8.7
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├─┬ @babel/template@7.8.6
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ └─┬ @babel/code-frame@7.8.3
17 silly saveTree │   │ │   └─┬ @babel/highlight@7.8.3
17 silly saveTree │   │ │     └── js-tokens@4.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├─┬ @babel/traverse@7.8.6
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ ├─┬ @babel/helper-function-name@7.8.3
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ │ └── @babel/helper-get-function-arity@7.8.3
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ ├── @babel/helper-split-export-declaration@7.8.3
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ ├─┬ debug@4.1.1
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ │ └── ms@2.1.2
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ └── globals@11.12.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├── @babel/types@7.8.7
17 silly saveTree │   │ └── semver@6.3.0
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ istanbul-lib-report@2.0.8
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├── istanbul-lib-coverage@2.0.5
17 silly saveTree │   │ └─┬ make-dir@2.1.0
17 silly saveTree │   │   └── pify@4.0.1
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ istanbul-lib-source-maps@3.0.6
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├─┬ debug@4.1.1
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ └── ms@2.1.2
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├── istanbul-lib-coverage@2.0.5
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├─┬ make-dir@2.1.0
17 silly saveTree │   │ │ └── pify@4.0.1
17 silly saveTree │   │ └── source-map@0.6.1
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ istanbul-reports@2.2.7
17 silly saveTree │   │ └── html-escaper@2.0.0
17 silly saveTree │   ├─┬ js-yaml@3.13.1
17 silly saveTree │   │ ├── argparse@1.0.10
17 silly saveTree │   │ └── esprima@4.0.1
17 silly saveTree │   └─┬ make-dir@2.1.0
17 silly saveTree │     ├── pify@4.0.1
17 silly saveTree │     └── semver@5.7.1
17 silly saveTree ├─┬ karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
17 silly saveTree │ └── karma-jasmine@1.1.2
17 silly saveTree ├── karma-jasmine@1.1.2
17 silly saveTree ├─┬ karma@4.0.1
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ body-parser@1.19.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── bytes@3.1.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── content-type@1.0.4
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── depd@1.1.2
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.7.2
17 silly saveTree │ │ │ └── inherits@2.0.3
17 silly saveTree │ │ └── qs@6.7.0
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ connect@3.7.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ └─┬ finalhandler@1.1.2
17 silly saveTree │ │   ├── encodeurl@1.0.2
17 silly saveTree │ │   └── escape-html@1.0.3
17 silly saveTree │ ├── di@0.0.1
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ dom-serialize@2.2.1
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── custom-event@1.0.1
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── ent@2.2.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ └── extend@3.0.2
17 silly saveTree │ ├── flatted@2.0.1
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ http-proxy@1.18.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── eventemitter3@4.0.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ └─┬ follow-redirects@1.10.0
17 silly saveTree │ │   └─┬ debug@3.2.6
17 silly saveTree │ │     └── ms@2.1.2
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ isbinaryfile@3.0.3
17 silly saveTree │ │ └─┬ buffer-alloc@1.2.0
17 silly saveTree │ │   ├── buffer-alloc-unsafe@1.1.0
17 silly saveTree │ │   └── buffer-fill@1.0.0
17 silly saveTree │ ├─┬ log4js@4.5.1
17 silly saveTree │ │ ├── date-format@2.1.0
17 silly saveTree │ │ └─┬ debug@4.1.1
17 silly saveTree │ │   └── ms@2.1.2
17 silly saveTree │ ├── mime@2.4.4
17 silly saveTree │ └── source-map@0.6.1
17 silly saveTree ├── moment@2.24.0
17 silly saveTree ├── ngx-image-cropper@2.0.2
17 silly saveTree └─┬ node-sass@4.13.1
17 silly saveTree   ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
17 silly saveTree   │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
17 silly saveTree   │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
17 silly saveTree   └── cross-spawn@3.0.1
18 verbose stack Error: Invalid package name "no,rmalize-path": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
18 verbose stack     at invalidPackageName (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:82:15)
18 verbose stack     at Result.setName (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:118:11)
18 verbose stack     at new Result (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:107:23)
18 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:54:15)
18 verbose stack     at module.exports (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/realize-shrinkwrap-specifier.js:21:14)
18 verbose stack     at /home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:54:23
18 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotValue (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:155:18)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotAccum (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:144:25)
18 verbose stack     at Object.tryCatcher (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
19 verbose cwd /home/administartor/projects/ATS-Candidate-frontend/ats-candidate-frontend
20 verbose Linux 4.15.0-88-generic
21 verbose argv "/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/bin/node" "/home/administartor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/bin/npm" "i"
22 verbose node v12.5.0
23 verbose npm  v6.9.0
24 error code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
25 error Invalid package name "no,rmalize-path": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: @SujeetSinha I updated my question with package json file.

Comment: There is no issue in your `package.json`. Can you also share `/home/administartor/.npm/_logs/2020-03-28T05_08_25_516Z-debug.log`?

Comment: Also, if `npx-image-cropper` was the package after which you got the issue, try removing it from the `dependencies` section from your `package.json` and then `npm install`

Comment: @SujeetSinha I have added the log file. I had to remove few line from it since body is limited to 30000 characters here. Also there is no npx-image-cropper in my packge.json file

Comment: my bad, it was `ngx-image-cropper`. I see it in the file.

Comment: @SujeetSinha I tried but no luck.

Comment: @AKSHAYSALEKAR Can you delete package-lock.json and try executing npm-install?